# SSIS Catalog environment variables

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to use environment variables to define parameters for my connection strings at run time.

I tried to follow [some guides online](http://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2015/1/4/parameterizing-connections-and-values-at-runtime-using-ssis-environment-variables) . So I defined the parameter in the package:

[image]

Now to the problem : 
 The guide works, the only problem is that every time a package is executed, I need to manually choose the environment folder I want to use, although I already did it in the package.

[image]

> SSIS doesn't presume to know which environment to use (even if only one exists)

How do I override this?

I saw I can use a  scheduled Job, and tell it which environment to use, but that's not helpfull for me since I'm running my package via a service and a procedure . I need some way of telling it which environment to choose.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot set one environment for good - the idea for environments is that you choose which one you want to be used during the execution. As you pointed out, you can do that in a job. So does that mean that agent jobs have super-natural powers? No. If you script a job with a step which executes a package referencing an environment, you will see a familiar dtexec command, e.g.:

```
    /ISSERVER "\"\SSISDB\test\test1\Incremental.dtsx\"" /SERVER "\"DESKTOP-NT4K1HQ\"" 
/ENVREFERENCE 1 /Par "\"$ServerOption::LOGGING_LEVEL(Int16)\"";1 
/Par "\"$ServerOption::SYNCHRONIZED(Boolean)\"";True /CALLERINFO SQLAGENT /REPORTING E
```

What I would like to highlight here is the **/ENVREFERENCE 1** parameter - here is how the agent job knows which environment to choose.

So the answer to your question is that you always need to choose an environment while executing a package (of course if you want one to be used). In case of a catalog procedure you would do something like (per [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/system-stored-procedures/catalog-create-execution-ssisdb-database)):

```
    EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[create_execution] @package_name=N'Child1.dtsx', @execution_id=@execution_id OUTPUT, @folder_name=N'TestDeply4', @project_name=N'Integration Services Project1', 
@use32bitruntime=False, 
@reference_id=1
```

Where `@reference_id = 1` is your environment reference. In order to find your environment's ID you have to query the `[SSISDB].[catalog].[environments]` view.

Did I answer your question or do you execute your packages in a different way? If you are sure that you will never need more than one environment then that woulld be a sign that you do not need environment variables at all.

Comment: Thanks for the answer . I will need to use more then 1 environment (DEV,QA,PROD..) . My problem is that I'm executing the package like this -> I have a web service, which sends parameters to an SP in the DB, which execute the package with `start_execution` , which throw an error that I didn't provide a value to this parameter. My intention was to use the environment variables for connections string so it can easily be hard coded and changed if necessary. Do I need to change it maybe to depend on a table in the DB ?

Comment: Environment variables are a good way to achieve what you need, but you still have to be able to determine the context while creating the execution (you must do this prior to calling start_execution). I'd say that you can either pass an environment ID via a parameter from your web service to the stored procedure or create a config table in which you would store the IDs or environment names.

Comment: Another idea: establish the environment you need by assing them names that would match your database/server name (depends how you seperate your environments). Then by querying the [SSISDB].[catalog].[environments] view you could extract the environment ID using the db/server name.